# Prev/Next links that follow a custom menu order?

Tags: menus, next-post-link

Is there a way to include prev/next links that follow a custom menu order? For example, let's say I have a custom menu set up like this:

- Project 1
- Project 2

  - Subproject 1
  - Subproject 2
- Project 3

I would like there to be prev/next links on each of those items with the buttons corresponding to the menu order rather than chronological order. To further elaborate, Project 2 would have prev/next links, with the former leading to Project 1 and the latter leading to Subproject 1. Project 3 would only have a link for prev since it's the last item in the menu. Subproject 2 would have prev/next links, with the former leading to Subproject 1 and the latter leading to Project 3.

Comment: In what context are you using the prev/next functions?  Are these posts or pages or a custom post type? Is this a page that uses a custom query to generate the results or a default WP archive listing?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links